# PHP Installation

Tags: php, installation

I am a student and this year we are introduced with a new subject called PHP. I want to save and use PHP files on my windows 8 64 bit. How to execute these files? What all to install? Please help.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImZEwrHohRg

Comment: @yahoo Or yahoo! it?

Comment: You can download and install xampp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreed with @devon, WAMP OR XAMPP are best to start with and please make sure to make some common changes to make coding easy.

Easy to learn from here:
http://www.phpknowhow.com/basics/working-with-xampp/

Answer (score 1):

A good place to get started with PHP is by [installing WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/). This is a development environment that will setup an apache server running PHP and MySQL on your windows machine. This way you can run PHP based web-apps all directly on your own computer (via localhost).